# Make client software connect to the hidden service without modification of source code

Tags: support

I have client and server software. They use single TCP-IP port to send data between client and server. Both made for Ubuntu. Both of them can not use socks proxy.

I want to use Tor to hide server's IP from clients. And I need solution without modification of app's source code.

First of all I can launch hidden service.

As I understand server software should not be modified to support Tor incoming connections. I just add HiddenServicePort instruction in torrc file on the server and traffic will be redirected to the server app.

But how can I setup client side to connect to the hidden service?
I can set up redirection of all outgoing traffic to the Tor (i.e. Transparent proxy).
But client software needs to "resolve" .onion address. Can this be done without modification of client software? Any configuration of the Tor/Ubuntu is possible.

Comment: Why are you asking this in the Meta site?

Comment: Does your software support HTTP proxies by any chance? If so, you can set up Privoxy as a kind of middle-man between your program and Tor.